# When encrypting a column in Sybase does it generates a log?

Tags: sql, database, sybase, sap-ase

So lets say I want to encrypt a column in Sybase and that column has 1 or X million records:

1.- Is it as slow as an update?

2.- Does it generates a log?

Using Sybase ASE
I dont't want to drop the table and recreate it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure about the logging, but I do know that it can take a while on a large table, so it is probably a bit slower than an update on the same unecrypted column, as the encryption adds to the length of the column.

My experience leads me to believe it is at least partially logged, otherwise it would not be recoverable should an error occur during the conversion from plain text to cipher text.

If you do not want to drop and recreate your table, your options are a bit limited.

### bcp out/in

1. `bcp` the data out of your table.
2. `truncate` table
3. `alter table` and modify column(s) with encryption
4. `bcp` data back into table - Use fast bcp (no triggers or indexes) to avoid logging.

### Select Into

1. `select into` from your existing table into a temp table, encrypting the column(s) in the process.
2. `truncate` table
3. `alter` table and modify column(s) with encryption
4. `select into` from temp table back into production table.

[Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.5 > Encrypted Columns Users Guide > Encrypting Data > Specifying encryption on new tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00968.1550/html/Encryption/BAJJCCFH.htm)